# Is it possible to run Java on arm?

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, java, arm, minecraft

I have a couple of spare Raspberry Pi 4's from a project last year. I was recently thinking that it would be really cool to run a Minecraft server on them, afterall they now have 4gb ram and a quad core cpu. Minecraft servers run on a *.jar* file and I found that oracle does *not offically support Arm.*

Comment: As well as Stephen Kitt's openjdk answer, there's also an open source minecraft clone called [minetest](https://www.minetest.net/), which doesn't require java (it's mostly written in C++).   It's **not** minecraft, but it's similar.  Packages for client and server are available for debian and ubuntu and probably other distros too.

Comment: Isn't Java installed by default in Raspberry Pi OS?

Answer (score 3):

You don’t need an “official” Java from Oracle, [OpenJDK](https://openjdk.java.net/) is available and just as official; on your Raspberry Pi,

```
sudo apt install default-jre
```

will install the runtime environment, and

```
sudo apt install default-jdk
```

will install the development kit.

A large number of Java packages are available, [this list gives details per release of Raspberry Pi OS](https://www.raspberryconnect.com/raspbian-packages/75-raspbian-java). All these packages [come from Debian](https://packages.debian.org/stable/java/) and are also available in Ubuntu.